# wrong AES decryption result

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decrypt a server response using AES (256/ECB) but getting a wrong result. When I try the same inputs with [this](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/) online tool I get the right result but running my code is giving a wrong result. Here's my decryption code

```
 //input is a Hex encoded String of the response     
 public String decryptString(String input){
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decodeHex(key),"AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(input));
    String outputString = Base64.encodeBase64String(output);
    return outputString;
}
```

The parameters I entered into the online tool are  :
key = 57e17ae84ceb2938c1f464e902f004919ea08fa7de5e358d1df028fde98d456d

input = 1c6f645bed9019332e94b69bd0152015b41dfce6c7f83046a59e1f80bce302a1ea59ccd15adbd7fcd5e7579cdaea1178fa9540ff0afa74cfe85c4e3244f9255f6dc3808b76088203bf28af25191d9d79487a2f7fb3a53bf7ee50d735d748dd16fbc3f19f9ebcf33a44d95bb221ef47fb577450d207ce6c5b762dc70142c9b7c1d815137ce24bf34fd0f5d2e0ab618c9087ef62327657f1f6c31f164109a4d190973c998e02971e6438dfc1af8dffc28cad0aa9a91a62f57d15200934cd18935b93d7327f7f8a41498ac416d90316a963cc736ce5d4fcde8401ec2f83714c4b202ddb69ce5fde1b61d69caadc2c7a162d7e88f2c5c671832f0bc4f14c98a4e2b9c4c84666a60530623f17c2f960b60c4a7242e10752cb863d41153c451dfc7d5cc4e2e9a8f8c0641764c8fca05f7db2b6

Comment: What exact parameters did you enter into the online tool? Please note the default "AES" parameters in Java are AES/CBC/Pkcs5padding and zero IV vector . Did you use CBC  mode with proper padding?

Comment: @gusto2 I updated my question with the values. AFAIK the defaults for AES in java are AES/ECB/Pkcs5padding which uses no IV vector.

Comment: The problem is that the defaults are different in Oracle Java and Android. That's why `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` is an anti-pattern: it's not portable and there is no advantage to relying on defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to share the answer in case anyone stumbles into the same problem. 
The result was actually the right result, the missing part was encoding the resulting byte array as a string using UTF-8 charset. The function becomes

```
public String decryptString(String input){
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decodeHex(key),"AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(input));
    String outputString = new String(output,"UTF-8");
    return outputString;
}
```